# Consecutive Schengen area visas from different countries?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am currently living in Germany, using a one-year working holiday visa.  When that expires, I hope to move to another European country, and continue this pattern of moving countries for as long as I'm eligible for visas.

I know that without a visa, as an Australian I can only stay in the Schengen area for 90 days out of every 180.

- Is it going to be fine to apply for a Schengen visa (probably another 1-year working holiday) visa for another country, immediately consecutive to my current visa - i.e. starting the day my current one ends?
- When my visa here expires, do I need to leave the country immediately, or can I stay for up to 90 days before leaving?

Comment: So you will apply for a Schengen visa giving the authority your passport with a Schengen visa already in it.  Unless the consulate worker will choose to ignore it you won't get another one.

Comment: @Karlson, if you have a Schengen visa, can you not apply for another (in another country)? That sounds like an answer to what I am asking, and worried about.

Comment: You can certainly apply but since visa is the same for all of those countries...

Comment: "..."?  I hate to sound stupid, but I don't know what goes after that ellipsis.  Is it not normal / possible / legal to have two working holiday / Schengen visas one after the other?  Although it gives access to all countries in the zone, it's issued by a specific country, isn't it?

Comment: Let's apply a little of common sense.  Since you are applying to Schengen Visa which applies to all countries doesn't it mean that a visa granted by one country would be considered the same as visa granted by another?  So why exactly would France grant you a new visa in violation of treaties, if Germany granted you visa already?

Comment: Common sense?  Please don't be patronising, @Karlson.  I wouldn't have asked if I already knew.  So what you're saying, after all that, is that no two Schengen-zone countries can give a visa in succession to each other?  Could you link to that please?  I am (obviously) not aware that's the case.

Comment: Why is the linked question a duplicate?  It asks about illegally staying past the 90 days and if they will be deported, which is *definitely not* what I am asking. In fact I have made clear I am interested in legal avenues. My question is about the possibility of getting a visa in one country after having one in another, which appears to have been answered in the comments, just not as an answer.  It's definitely a different question though.

Comment: @Karlson But the point is precisely that a work-holiday visa (or any visa for a stay longer than 3 months) *does not apply to all countries*.

Answer (score 5):

Staying some time in the Schengen area after your current visa expires is possible as the time under the work-holiday visa does not count toward the 90-day limit, see [Does tourist visa (90 days) apply after a long-term visa ends in Schengen countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777)

Applying for a work-holiday visa from another country should also be no problem, at least as far as Schengen regulations are concerned. The basic principle is that long-stay visas are still national matters, not subject to the Schengen-wide restrictions on short stay (“Schengen visa” is a bit of a misnomer in this case, there are major differences between Schengen uniform short-stay visas and national long-term visas from Schengen countries).

If you are eligible under local law, a Schengen member state can certainly grant you a national visa starting immediately after another long-term national visa (from the same country or from another Schengen country). One thing you need to be mindful of is that it's sometimes impossible to apply for a long-stay visa from within the country (even if you would otherwise qualify for the visa) but some countries do allow it.

Importantly, none of this is true for short-stay visas (Schengen uniform type C visas) or, for Australian citizens, to visa-free short stays. In that case, the 90-day rule applies and it applies to you as a person. Getting another short-stay visa or using another passport does not entitle you to another 90 days in the Schengen area.

Finally, there is one last legal way to stay a bit longer in the Schengen area after having exhausted all work-holiday visas and visa-free short stays using prior bilateral agreements between Australia and specific Schengen member states. In particular, you should be able to get [another 90 days in Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens) if your previous 90 days were spent elsewhere and possibly to stay longer in Germany as well.