# Sleep/stay at the Stuttgart airport without a visa

Tags: visas, germany, airports, stuttgart

I am from Brazil and I am going to work in Germany for 6 months.
My insurance coverage starts on August 1, but because of the high prices I bought my airline ticket for July 30. I will get to Stuttgart on the next day (July 31).

Today I was informed at the embassy that I am not allowed to do that because my visa will only become valid on August 1 due to the insurance coverage period.

So in case I am not able to change my insurance on time, am I allowed to sleep at the airport until the next day? Or at least wait there for a few hours (I will get there at 6:35 pm, so it would be for less than 6 hours)?

Edit: I changed my insurance coverage. I'm now in Germany and I entered without any problems. In the end they didn't ask for an insurance neither in Brazil nor in Germany, just checked my passport.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean! It would be very expensive to change the date of the flight so if I could wait at the airport it would be great.

Comment: What sort of visa is that? What about getting another one for the day before?

Comment: It's a work visa, because we need a visa if we are going to stay for more than 3 months. I will try to change my insurance coverage, but I don't know if the embassy will allow. I can also try to enter Germany as a tourist, but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: @koplersky It depends on your citizenship and you will need insurance too but even with a Schengen visa it might cost something like EUR 80-100 so it could be worth it.

Comment: @Relaxed Sorry, but do you mean that it would cost 80-100 to apply for another insurance?

Comment: @koplersky I meant that a Schengen short-stay visa (which you could perhaps get to bridge the time until your work visa starts) costs EUR 60. With a travel insurance for a couple of days, a few EUR to copy documents, etc. it could cost EUR 80-100 in total. But in fact you don't even need a Schengen visa so it's just a matter of getting some cheap travel insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Doc is right that the main issue is getting to the airport. Waiting airside (i.e. before the passport control) is not a problem at some large European airports. It's probably very uncomfortable at a small airport like Stuttgart (where people typically wouldn't transit at all) but it might still be possible.

The real question is whether you have the right to be at the airport in the first place. If you don't, the airline should prevent boarding. In practice, it means you should either have the right to enter the destination or you should have an onward ticket and the right to transit without visa.

But in your case, as a Brazilian citizen, you can enter the Schengen area without visa so the airline probably won't check anything once you show your passport. The border guards might also let you in with minimal control, although you do need medical insurance and they can ask for some proof of it. So extending your insurance or getting another one for a couple of days is advisable in any case.

Caveat: I don't know anything about German work visas (whether you need a specific stamp, can enter beforehand and what not) but I don't think entering as a tourist shortly before should be problem.

Comment: I was able to change my insurance and now the coverage starts on July 30 and ends on February 28. It's true that Brazilians don't need a visa when staying less than 90 days, but besides the insurance I also need a return ticket. Do you think they might see a problem when they realize that I am entering as a tourist but both my return ticket and my insurance coverage indicate that I am going to stay longer than 90 days?

Comment: @koplersky It's not forbidden to stay as a tourist before or after a long stay visa like your work visa, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/getting-a-tourist-schengen-visa-after-working-visa/24776#24776.

Answer (score 5):

You will almost certainly not be allowed to board your plane from your origin airport.

The airline is responsible for confirming that you have a valid visa to enter the country you're travelling to.  Given that your visa is not valid until the day after arrival, they will most likely not let you board the flight as doing so would leave them liable to a fine for delivering you to the country without a valid visa.

It's possible that they may not notice the starting date, but that's really not something you'd want to rely on.

Secondly, according to [Sleeping In Airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/stuttgart.htm), "You will be permitted to stay inside the terminal overnight with a valid ticket", however you will not have a valid (outgoing) ticket so it's likely you will not be allowed stay.

Comment: If I get another insurance coverage for the July 31, do you think I could enter Germany as a tourist? We need a visa only if we are going to stay longer than 90 days.

Comment: @koplersky Rule No. 1 always mention your nationality, if you don't it **will** create ambiguity and confusion. If we know your nationality we can assess everything else from it.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Sorry, I edited my post and added my nationality. Thank you!