# Staying in Schengen after student visa expires

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a question. I'm a USA citizen with a student visa issued in Sweden that expires on the 30 of June. However, I am planning on leaving Schengen (through Sweden) and returning after the 30 of June to Spain.

Will I be able to enter Spain using my 90 tourist days?

I read that time spent under a residence permit does not count towards those 90 days, however I would like to confirm this.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/getting-a-tourist-schengen-visa-after-working-visa/24776#24776 (US citizen but working visa) and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen?lq=1 (Australian after a Working Holiday Visa).

Comment: Thanks. I knew this question was quite a duplicate. However, I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Just updating this: I did my trip without any problem.