# Traveling Around Europe

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, us-citizens

I am studying Abroad in Italy for exactly 89 days but I am wanting to visit family friends and family while already in Europe. My schedule is hopefully..

> Italy - 3 months
>
> UK - 2 weeks
>
> Germany - 1 month
>
> Spain - 2 months

Do I need to get visas for both Spain and Germany or can I just get one long term visa for Spain and still visit Germany first?
I am an American Citizen :)

Comment: Do you already have a student visa for Italy?

Comment: Also have a look at [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/getting-a-tourist-schengen-visa-after-working-visa). If you have a student visa for your 89 days, then it will answer your other questions.

Comment: On what visa are you travelling to Italy?

Comment: I don't think you need to get any special visa to visit any of those countries for tourism/visiting friends and family. Germany and Spain (and Italy) are in the Schengen zone and you are allowed 90 days within the zone.  The UK is not in the zone but you are fine https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism