# Can I travel to France for the second time with my visa type D?

Tags: visas, france, long-stay-visas

I was doing exchange programme in France for 4 months. For this, I got the visa for a long stay. Particulars mentioned on my visa are:

1. France (sauf CTOM)
2. From 22-08-2013 till 22-02-2014
3. Type of visa : D
4. Numbers of entries: MULT
5. Duration of stay XXX.

I finished my programme in December. Now, I'd like to visit my friends there in February for a week. So, can I reuse my visa again or should I get a new one?

Comment: What exactly does the visa say, especially about “Durationofstay”?

Comment: It says just 'XXX'.

Comment: Depending on your citizenship, you might also stay in France under regular Schengen area visa-free short stay rules [as your earlier stay under the French long-stay visa does not count toward the 90-day limit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777).

Comment: What citizenship are you?

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot.**

I was doing a study abroad in France with the same visa and an OFII stamp associated with it. I was specifically told by the Consulate in Atlanta that I had a leverage of 5 days either before or after the official duration of my study abroad program.

Thus, legally, you do not have permission to stay in the country after the exchange program is over. The duration says XXX precisely because of this reason, because the duration of the program can vary depending on the specifics of the program.

Once your program is over (designated on an official program letter submitted to the embassy/consulate) and you leave the Schengen area, you should ideally not be allowed to enter the Schengen area again on the same visa.