# Resident permit finishes, can I travel on 90 day visa

Tags: schengen

I am a New Zealander on a resident permit in Holland. When my permit expires I plan to be travelling through France. Is this ok under the 90 day visa? I am exiting the Schengen zone for a weekend in London soon but will re enter to Holland living for another month before leaving to France.. Am I ok?

Dates:

Permit expires 9/9/14
Will be in France 10/9/14 returning home to NZ from Spain on 16/9/14
Travelling outside of schengen zone 18/7/14 for a weekend.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777

Comment: See also http://www.nzembassy.com/france/nzers-overseas/living-in-france/travel-within-france-and-europe for the NZ-specific aspects.

Comment: Technically, what you get is a 90 days visa-free stay and not a visa, but it should be fine. As a New Zealander, you might even be able to stay longer in the Schengen area, if you choose carefully which countries you go to.

Answer (score -1):

Your Dutch resident permit will not automatically transform into a 90-day visitor visa. You must take active steps to make that happen. Not really a problem, when you leave the Schengen zone just stop at Immigration and ask them to cancel your nearly-expired resident permit. Or you can do it on the way back in, whichever is easier.

Under no circumstances do either of the following:

- be in Holland (or anywhere else in Europe) the day after your work permit expires.
- do any paid work while there with a 90-day visitor visa.

Comment: New Zealand citizens don't need and cannot get a short stay visa.

Comment: If i just go to UK and return then i can show the stamps that prove i have left the schengen zone? i thought the NZ 90 day free visa you didnt actually get a physical visa?

Comment: @Andrew Indeed, you won't get a visa. The main issue is proving you haven't overstayed when leaving the Schengen area. That's why being outside of the Schengen area when your visa expires and getting an entry stamp afterwards would make things easier. But showing your residence permit should also be enough (do keep it).