# Internship in Switzerland after French student visa

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, study

I am a US student studying in Paris for the spring semester. I am in the process of getting my student visa, which will be valid until mid-July.

However, I am planning to intern in Switzerland until mid-August. Once I leave France, am I able to stay in Switzerland? and for how long? Or must I leave the Schengen zone? I'm trying to figure out how I can make this work.

What is required (visa?) by Switzerland for US citizens that want to be interns?

Comment: As this question is about long-term arrangements, our sister site at [Expatriates.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com) may be better equipped to help you.

Comment: I'm more wondering if I would be able to stay in SWITZERLAND after my FRENCH visa expires and for how long

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed, it is about short-stay (the long-stay visa is a background element, not what the question is about). It is also closely related to earlier questions that were deemed on topic and seems similar to the “working holiday visa” questions we are happy to accept.

Comment: For me it is off-topic because it is about internships under student visa. The center question is what Switzerland requires for interns, and that is in my opinion more related to work visas (off-topic) than travelling. Unless, maybe, the internship is particularly short (<1 month), but that is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Vince Once again, the student visa is for **France**, the OP is asking about staying in Switzerland **after that** and indeed explicitly about a one-month stay from mid-July to mid-August! But in any case, we have many questions about stays longer than a month and about work (and in particular about “work holiday visa”) so your criteria do not seem to reflect established practice on this site.

Comment: @Relaxed for me it is unclear whether the stay in France is effectively until mid-July or if the 2 stays will overlap. Anyway, I think we reach the limit between on- and off-topic questions. There is a [meta question to deal with them](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/are-expat-questions-on-topic) but there is no clear rationale behind the upvoted answer. My interpretation is that we restrict to business and tourism travels. Work & Holiday visas count because the work is to finance tourism. In my opinion internships are pure work, not about tourism. Let's see what votes say

Comment: @Vince We are getting into theological arguments here… The question is entirely about short-stay regulations and explicitly about a one-month stay. It's not materially different from WHV or “can I visit the Schengen area after a long-stay visa” which already cover, there is no reason to make it off-topic. Incidentally, it's also off-topic according to the expat's website own rules so encouraging the OP to go there is absurd.

Answer (score 6):

You can enter Switzerland and stay there, for 90 days, under the usual rules which allow visa-free visits to the Schengen area for US citizens. The time spent in France under your French long-stay visa do not count towards these 90 days, see e.g. [Does tourist visa (90 days) apply after a long-term visa ends in Schengen countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777)

However I don't think you are allowed to do an internship in Switzerland without a Swiss visa/authorization (especially since I seem to recall that internships must be paid there), even during the validity period of your French visa.