# Tourist Visa After Student Visa in Schengen Zone

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, study, tourist-visas

I am an Australian in Spain on a 8 month student visa. I'm wondering if I can apply for the 90 day tourist visa while I'm here. Another option may be to leave to a non-Schengen zone like UK and return to Spain to start the 90 day visa. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

As an Australian citizen, you cannot get a short-stay Schengen visa under any circumstances. You can however stay in the Schengen area for 90 days without a visa, even if you have stayed in a Schengen country on a long-stay visa before.

See [Does tourist visa (90 days) apply after a long-term visa ends in Schengen countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/) and in particular [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/24777#24777) for the relevant law and [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/does-tourist-visa-90-days-apply-after-a-working-holiday-visa-ends-in-schengen/35406#35406) for an example of someone who did just that.