# Travel within Schengen area with just passport

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

My question is can you travel withing the Schengen area with only your passport if you are not a European citizen?
Is a passport sufficient to show your ID or do you need to provide the residence permit of the country you are currently staying in at all times? 
The nationality of the person travelling is Iranian and they are travelling from Sweden to Germany. They reside in Sweden and have applied for an extension to their visa but still no word has come from the Swedish migration board yet and they need to travel to Germany for a work event. So, can they go to Germany and come back without being required to show the residence permit for Sweden at the gate check or somewhere else?

Comment: Should be opened . Question is clear now and the answer is "yes".

Comment: Michael, when you say the answer is "yes", to which part of the question you are answering? Do you mean yes, a non european can travel within schengen with a passport?

Comment: @Neusser OP's talking about an ID Card from the tax authority (as opposed to the police), which is **not** tied to citizenship and **cannot** be used as a travel document. (Source, I'm Swedish)

Comment: @Mehrdad If not flying on a low-cost carrier and only having hand luggage, they will usually only have to show their boarding pass. When flying on a low-cost carrier such as Ryanair, both a valid passport and valid residence permit is required. If flying on a normal carrier with checked luggage, at least a passport is required at bag drop, but I'm not sure about the residence permit

Comment: @JonathanReez See my answer to Neusser

Comment: @Coke perhaps consider adding a canonical here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76180/can-i-travel-within-the-schengen-area-if-i-currently-dont-have-a-valid-visa-or